FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime version=8.0.0.0"
I have been working on a .NET 8 project in Visual Studio for months. Everything was working well until one day out of nowhere, without changing anything in the code/OS/VS the project started throwing this exception whenever I try to run it:
Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime version=8.0.0.0"

Here's what I've tried and hasn't worked:

Reinstalling Visual Studio
Reinstalling .NET
Repairing .NET
Restoring NuGet packages
Deleting bin and obj folders from my project, cleaning and rebuilding the solution
Cloning the repository again
Manually reinstalled NuGet packages/dependencies
Deleting NuGet cache
Manually installed System.Runtime via NuGet (it wasn't previously installed but it used to work just fine)

Curiously enough, when I try to run the project in Rider instead of VS on a different machine, the project runs just fine. I have seen many people encounter this error online but none of their approaches worked for me.
The .sln has only one project whose .NET version is 8.

Is the problem related to the project or does a new project show the same result ?

A new project doesn't show the same result

It may be a good case to "report a problem" to microsoft. They may look into it, ask for logs, instruct you how to get logs, look at first error in logs (totally unrelated), tell you something unrelated and then stop talking to you.. or your experience may be more pleasant and resultful.

Try probing the assembly loading process using the COREHOST_TRACE* environment variables, and progressively increasing the VERBOSITY level. See if the log gives you anything useful.

If it worked before my guess is a nuget reference got updated ? Check all recent changes to the code and maybe you find something that changed.

Open Terminal and run below command to check whether the runtime is installed or not.
dotnet --list-runtimes

you can direct download .Net core runtime using below link
.Net Core Runtime Version 8.0.0.0

Thanks, it is installed... I'm not sure there's something else I need to do in order for the project to access it but it was working three days ago without me doing anything so I don't know.
